# Jhipster exception handling in services

Tags: exception, jhipster

i am currently trying to understand the exception handling in JHipster.

I want to throw an exception in a service. The exception message shall be translated in the UI and parameters shall be set for the message. The `CustomParameterizedException` would fit perfectly. But from an architectural perspective, i think i can't use it in a service, as the exception is located in the web package. Why is it located in the web package? I would expect it to be in an own package `exception` or similar, so it can be accessed from every layer in the application.

I've also seen in the `ExceptionTranslator.processRuntimeException` method, that any `RuntimeException` can be handled, if the `ResponseStatus` annotation is set on the Exception. As far as i can see, the translation in the UI will only be done based on the error code. So i cannot use it for custom error messages, that i need.

How do you do the exception handling in other layers than the web layer in a jHipster application?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`CustomParameterizedException`  is in a web package because it uses `ParameterizedErrorVM` which is a view model which gets serialized in JSON and used by Angular part of your app. This is generated code, feel free to change it  to fit your needs.

Spring MVC offers several ways to handle exceptions as shown in this [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).

You could also uses AOP to implement a default processing like logging or translating exceptions, see `LoggingAspect` in your JHipster app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!I want to understand the intention of the way it is generated by JHipster. From my perspective the usage of the `ParameterizedErrorVM` is not sufficient. Couldn't it also be a DTO, as it is done with the UserDTO on the service layer? That way the exception could also be used in the service layer. More complex, data-related validations should be done in the service layer i think. In my opinion it would fit well to also use the `CustomParameterizedException` here too.

Comment: Feel free to propose a PR on github project

Comment: Ok, i will do so, as soon as i got it running well in my application.